# Sequence of Orthogonal Polynomials: Three-term recursive relation - Why can we generate a sequence from this?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a theorem in the subject of sequences of orthogonal polynomials telling:

**Theorem:**
Let $p_0, p_1 \ldots$ be a sequence of orthogonal polynomials. Let $a_i$ denote the lead coefficient of $p_i$ for each $i$, and define $p_{-1}(x)$ to be the zero polynomial. Then $\alpha_{n+1}p_{n+1}(x)=(x-\beta_{n+1})p_n(x)-\alpha_n\gamma_np_{n-1}(x)$ for $n \ge 0$ where $\alpha_0=\gamma_0=1$ and $\alpha_n = \frac {a_{n-1}} {a_n}, \beta_n = \frac {\langle p_{n-1},xp_{n-1}\rangle} {\langle p_{n-1},p_{n-1}\rangle}, \gamma_n = \frac {\langle p_{n},p_{n}\rangle} {\langle p_{n-1},p_{n-1}\rangle}$.

This theorem tells that for any sequence $\{p_n\}$ of orthogonal polynomials the condition is neccesary ?

However, why can I use the theorem to recursively construct a sequence of orthogonal polynomials ? The statement is not on the form "if and only if", it is only one-way ?

Answer (score 0):

The theorem you want is 
 Favard's theorem, also called the Shohat–Favard theorem covered on Wikipedia.